# Disabling syncing the clock in Windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, windows-10

So it doesn't matter if I set "Set time automatically" to off or go to internet time and disable the synchronizing with the server (and I turned off adjusting for dst too), windows still changes my time to my current timezone after a restart or a few hours.

I checked the "Windows Time" service also and it's disabled. This not only happens in a single PC, all my machines have this problem. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have no additional clocks or weird stuff like that. Just a plain installation will work as described. I also can't just "choose the right timezone". That's not a solution, cause it's the minutes I want to change.

Any ideas why Windows keeps synchronizing my time when it shouldn't?

Comment: What time zone do you set it to and what time zone does it reset too?

Comment: Is it a dual boot system? I've had issues with one OS wanting to change the bios clock which affects the other OS negativly

Comment: @Blaine nope, it's not =(. Also it happens in 2 different machines

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't matter what time zone i put it to. It resets to that timezone. I don't want it to use internet time, that's all

Comment: can't you uncheck the "set time automatically" or "set time zone automatically" checkboxes?

Comment: @Blaine I did already. I said that in my post =(

Comment: I don’t think what you’re trying to do should be done. There is really no need whatsoever to offset your PC’s time by a few _minutes_. If you think you really need it, you should perhaps explain the reasons in your question.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the [Synchronize with an Internet Time Sever](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/20105d1432837839-clock-synchronize-internet-time-server-windows-10-a-time_synchronize-2.png) is unchecked? Are any of these PC's on a domain?

Comment: @DrZoo yes, I have. I said it in my post "or go to internet time and disable the synchronizing with the serve". Thanks a lot though! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers

As a last resort, delete the servers in the registry.

Comment: great! I tried this. If it doesn't change by tomorrow I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just remember to boot as such info is usually read once at start-up.

Comment: I'm trying to upvote your answer as well as accepting it but I ran out of reputation to do so apparently, haha. Thanks a lot, this worked

Answer (score 2):

If these PCs are part members of a Active Directory domain, then this is the default behavior.

The Kerberos system that is used as part of the authentication of domain accounts uses a strict "time out" system in order to prevent a "replay" attack.  The idea is that the time stamps on each request/response must be within an acceptable windows of tolerance (5 minutes by default).  So, to keep Kerberos working, all domain members sync their clocks with the domain controller by default.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779260%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

So, that means if you *are* somehow able to alter the time on your PC by more than 5 minutes, you won't be able to be authenticated on that PC via Active Directory.