# How to stop Win10 from correcting the date/time automatically

Tags: windows-10

I am testing some software that is date sensitive. In order to complete some of my tasks, I must change my test machine's date and time hundreds of times in a test. I have disabled W32Time in services,  set "Set time automatically" to "Off", and yet my machine will occasionally correct the date/time to today's date and time.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have it set to set the time zone automatically as well? This has given me trouble in the past.

Comment: I have that set to "Off" currently as well. When my time does sync, I'll find that `Set time automatically` has been turned back on, and `Set time zone automatically` is left off.

Comment: Try changing the service "Windows Time" to automatic and reboot, see if it sticks then

Answer (score 1):

(Not sure if I should edit my first answer, or post another)

Also, [this page](https://superuser.com/a/1079388/332891) suggests deleting the DateTime server list from the registry. That seems kind of extreme, but it may work.
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers`

Be sure to export the list as a backup first!

[Regedit export(screen cap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkfBy.png)

Edit: If your computer is part of a Domain, you won't be able to change the date-time, as its controlled by the Domain. Another thing, is if you are trying to change the date/time in a script or program, **you need to be running it as administrator**. [[info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/change-the-system-time)]

## Solution as a Program

As practice, I decided to quickly make a program that forces the date, date and time, or date offset every second. When the program exits, it restores the date and time. While not a direct solution to your problem, it does work around the undesired behavior you are experiencing.

- [Github link to source code in C#](https://github.com/othermusketeer/TimeTravel)
- [Precompiled binary (in a zip file)](https://github.com/othermusketeer/TimeTravel/releases/tag/v1.0)

Comment: You're generally better off using the `w32tm` tool rather than manually editing the registry, where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Is your test system physical or virtual? If virtual, you need to also disable the time sync on the properties of the VM instance, otherwise vmTools or the HyperV integration service is syncing the time on the guest.

Comment: I suggest rephrasing using just the if-then, dropping the leading question.  The substance of the answer is a useful distinction.  Clarifying questions are best left to comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-3088594/disable-set-time-automatically-feature-windows-registry.html), there is also a registry setting that can be changed.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters]
"Type"="NoSync"`

Comment: I already have that set to "NoSync", it will change back occasionally though :/

Comment: 1. If a dual-boot machine, Linux may be setting time to UTC.
2. Try setting time from BIOS (though obviously you don't want to do that frequently!).

Answer (score -1):

Is your system a private use computer or a computer connected to a network and managed by some system administration? Maybe your company policy or settings from administration overwrite your changes regarding the time.

Comment: This might be it, I'm not sure. It is a managed network, there's a domain. However the machine I am using is not signed into the domain, local accounts only.